# Creating Command Interface Styled HTML Site

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, css

I have been working on building a website with some base functionality that I would be able to add on to later if needed.

[image: Sample Website]

I would like users to be able to enter text into the "Type here..." input box and when they press enter it add a new line on their site based on the command they just typed.

For example if they entered "help" it would pint a few new lines explaining what the site does and some beginning commands. My idea is to continue to add commands to there would need to be some scalability to this. I have the website + input box working how I want it to.

```css
.headTag {
 background-color: lightgrey;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 26px;
}

.topPageTitle {
 color: black;
 font-size: 18px;
 float: left;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.mainPageText {
 color: black;
 font-size: 18px;
 float: right;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.userInput {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 10px;
}

.mainWindow {
 margin-top: 24px;
 font-family: typewriter;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: green;
 width: 100%
}

.mainWindow p {
 margin-top: -18px;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: typewriter;
  color: green;
  outline: none !important;
}
 

@font-face {
  font-family: typewriter;
  src: url('../assets/typewriter.ttf');
}

body {
 background-color: black;
 font-family: typewriter;
 color: lightgrey;
  background:#000;
}

.easyMenu {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5px;
 font-family: typewriter;
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 100%;
}

.easyMenu a {
 color: lightgrey;
 width: 24.5%;
 display:inline-block;
}

.easyMenu a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="headTag">
  <p class="mainPageText">13.04.2020</p>
 </div>
 <div class="mainWindow">
  <p>system>: Welcome to the Website.</p>
  <p>system>: If you are stuck or don't know what to do type "Help"</p>
 </div>
 <div class="userInput">
  <form>
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" id="fname" name="fname" value ="Type here..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="easyMenu">
  <a>>: Back</a>
  <a>>: Create Private Chat</a>
  <a>>: Join Private Chat</a>
  <a>>: Information</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally, I would like to stick with pure HTML+CSS however if JS if required happy to use it. I am also open to the idea of using Python WSGI to do this but would be unsure were to start this.

Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Kind regards
James

Comment: You need JavaScript to take action when they press Enter.

Comment: Use the `placeholder` attribute to display a temporary string in the input field.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Javascript to make it work: You need to use appendChild js command to make it work (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

[EDIT]
To resume what is said on the link, you should use the appendChild javaScript property that would allow you to add text on your page from the javascript code:

```js
function getCommand(input){
    if (input == "help"){
        let p = document.createElement("p"); //creates a new <p> element
        let text = document.createTextNode("Text you want to show");
        p.appendChild(text); // adds the text to the paragraph
        document.body.appendChild(p); // adds <p> to the body of your page
    }
    else {
        let p = document.createElement("p"); //creates a new <p> element
        let errorText = document.createTextNode("Invalid Command.");
        p.appendChild(errorText); // adds errorText to the <p> element
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

Hope I helped you with my answer,
Romain.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26426957)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice. I modified my answer as you told me to do.